# Java - Can I use an empty catch statement?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am working on a basic Java command line email client application. The connector I was provided with will send me emails, however if I "send" an email it will not be located on the connector as I created this email myself. Now when I want to delete an email I can find the folder I am in and delete it by its ID. I also want to delete it from the connector if its located inside the connector so that I will not receive this email again when I refresh emails.

```
public boolean delete(int messageId) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
{
if (folders.get(getActiveFolderName()).delete(messageId))
{
    if (connector.retrMessage(messageId) != null)
    {
    connector.markMessageForDeleting(messageId); 
    //throws exception if not found on connector
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

I tried this, is this a really bad way of going about handling exceptions?:

```
public boolean delete(int messageId)
{
if (folders.get(getActiveFolderName()).delete(messageId))
{
    try{
    connector.markMessageForDeleting(messageId);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    {
  //this successfully soaks up the exception if its not located in connector
    }
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't better to check if you have that element in the list/array instead of using the exception to control the flow?

Comment: Apart from the good answers you've already received, I'd have to say that `connector` must be quite poorly written to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as the _ONLY_ way to indicate that it doesn't have that message.

Answer (score 4):

Though they are considered as bad, as long as you are aware of what's going on and took necessary steps to recover from abnormal behaviour of the program, it will be fine.

I'm just suggesting to you to put at least a log statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally not think so. You are using the exception as an indicator of a particular result. You're not trying to hide some error in the code by not doing anything when you catch it. However, I'm not sure if you have the ability to change anything about this connector, but if so, you should adjust it so it isn't throwing errors like that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is called exception swallowing. It's generally considered bad practice. The risk is to swallow exceptions that might happen when your emails are located in the connector. You don't want that.

You already know a reason to have an IndexOutOfBoundsException, so why not test first if your email is located in the connector?

Answer (score 0):

It is always good practice to log any exception & then can be ignored in the cases like yours.

P.S.: No need to flood the log with stack trace in your case. It can be a simple error message indicating that the exception can be ignored safely.